# How to store function's returned value instead of function itself?

Tags: php, function, scope, return

Imagine this exemplary code:

```
$the_url = the_variable(); // this function returns "www.site.com/post123" here

$items = generate_array();

foreach($items as $item) {
   echo $the_url; // this function returns "www.site.com" here
}
```

Now, is it possible to store returned value of the_variable() as $the_url? Because it looks like it stores the function itself and runs it for every foreach iteration. So basically I want the foreach loop to return `www.site.com/post123` every time.

I know this is basic and simple, although I can't find a solution.

Comment: It **is** storing the return value.

Comment: No, that's not what it's doing. You're not interpreting things correctly. Even if `$the_url` *was* a function, you're not invoking it. The only way it's invoking a function each time is if you'd written `$the_url()`. Cannot answer this, as the code you've posted already does what you've asked how to do.

Comment: I'm using WordPress and there is posts loop in which $the_url returns the right url, there's also an inner loop where $the_url gets modified, so you're saying it is supposed to store the value not function itself? Why is it modifying my variable then? What might cause it?

Comment: Try echo $the_url(); if it errors, then it is because it is properly storing the string as desired.

Comment: Any chance of giving us the full the_variable() function code so we could duplicate it or at least have a better understanding? Are there any object references being returned?

Comment: In real life the_variable() stands for the_permalink() WordPress in-built function, here's it's source: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken. When you do this:

```
$var_name = function_name();
```

... `$var_name` is set to the **return** of `function_name()` - it is not a reference to that function.

Consider this example; if it were a reference, you would see a different number in each result:

```
function the_variable() {
    return 'http://www.test.com/' . rand(0, 100);
}

$the_url = the_variable();
$items = range(1, 20);

foreach($items as $item) {
   echo $the_url . PHP_EOL; 
}
```

However, [as you can see](https://eval.in/77815), it returns the first random number and that return is stored in `$the_url` until such a time as it may be redefined or unset.

As opposed to this example:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo the_variable() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Which **does** output a random number on the end each time.](https://eval.in/77822)